# Microsoft Add Ins; Add-Ins allowed, installed, but show greyed out for some users

Tags: ms-word, permissions, add-in, office365-apps

Admin windows user adds any Add-In. Admin is then able to see and use the Add-Ins in Microsoft Word without issue. However, when they push out any Add-In for their organization to other users, the Add-Ins show in the ribbon, but are individually greyed out.

O365 (most updated version) is deploying the Add-Ins to the users successfully, however, they cannot actually use/click on the installed Add-Ins. Microsoft boards only offer solutions on how to gain access to the Add-In functionality, there seems to be nothing about the Add-Ins themselves being individually greyed out.

BriefCatch Add-In is the example shown below but this behavior happens with ALL Add-Ins for Word.

[Correct view for Admin user:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD4Ib.png)

[Incorrect view persisting for other users:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFha.png)